# Changing vector inside std::transform on the same vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

I want to figure out if it is allowed to change the vector inside transform.
Consider the code:

```
std::vector<int> v;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) v.push_back(i);

for (auto &i : v) std::cout << i << " ";
std::cout << std::endl;
std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(v),
          [](auto i) { return i;});

for (auto &i : v) std::cout << i << " ";
std::cout << std::endl;
```

I expect to expand vector with elements which are based on exist vector contents. Here is the output:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

But if I replace begin and end with rbegin and rend correspondingly the output is following:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 0 0
```

I get unexpected 0 instead of 1 in a position before last. This makes me wonder if this code is a UB per se, and I should not rely on correct output with forward iterators as well.

Comment: The algorithm has undefined behavior at least because the vector can reallocate the used memory. In this case the iterators will be invalid.

Comment: That is what I suspect. I even tried different compiler versions and with MSVS compiler I managed to get some big arbitrary numbers in last two places. Is there a way to implement this algorithm without using additional vector? I need to do several iterations with the new data and I'm a bit reluctant to move vectors back and forth.

Comment: The question I linked both explains why your code triggers undefined behaviour (invalidation of iterators when reallocating) and how to properly use a vector while adding to the end of the same vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `for_each` above.  Certain changes in certain situations are valid, others are not.  Yours is not.  Generally iterator invalidation makes iteration invalid.  Adding or removing elements from a vector invalidates the end iterator (and all iterators at or after the point of insert/removal).  Reallocation invalidates all iterators.

Reverse iterators follow different rules based off the validity of thier base iterator.  But the forward case was UB already.